# How do I make row-based tuples from column range or list?

Tags: python-2.7, list, tuples

This is probably really simple but I'm not too clear.

Let's say I have a data frame and a list of column references. My goal is to make a list of tuples that give that row number's values for only the columns contained in my list.

```
raw_data = {'first_name': ['Jason', 'Molly', 'Tina', 'Jake', 'Amy'], 
    'last_name': ['Miller', 'Jacobson', 'Ali', 'Milner', 'Cooze'], 
    'sex': ['male', 'female', 'male', 'female', 'female'],
    'dog': ['Burt','Kane','Billy','Bob','Thorton'],
    'cat': ['Evil','PurrEvil','Rorry','Meowth','Killer'],
    'fish': ['Johhny','Nemo','Dorry','Jacob','Pinky']}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'sex'])

colref = ['dog','cat','fish']
```

I want to make a list of tuples like [['Burt','Evil','Johhny'],['Kane','PurrEvil','Nemo'],...]

but I want to do so without hardcoding column names or numbers. The real data set I am performing this on is much larger and variable in size but my list colref will always include all of the columns I want in my tuple list. Does anyone have any tips for me?

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have figured it out.. lol

```
tuples = [tuple(x) for x in df[colref].values]
```

If there is a better solution though please let me know. I'm having fun looking at other people's solutions to the problems I encounter as a noob.